# Check if a (2d domain) function has root in specific (small) region

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am a little confused that I couldn't find anything regarding this topic, sorry in case I was just too dumb for searching.

**My Problem**:
I have an array of 2d points/tuples `path` that describe a curve in the plane.
I want to get an array, same shape as path, that has boolean values for if a certain function has a root in proximity of the corresponding path point. By in proximity I mean somewhere in a disk with fixed radius around the point.

**What I did:** Basically nothing. I'm stuck at step one, directly after

```
import numpy as np

def func(x,y):
    res = 0
    ...some magic with res,x and y
    return res

has_roots = np.zeros_like(path, dtype = bool)
```

I thought I might use scipys fsolve to find all roots and then check if any roots are in proximity of my path points. My path is however very large (in total I will be considering several million points) so performance is crucial, and the comparison between path points and all roots would surely be a bottleneck.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: I assume that by root you mean values close to `y = 0`? So are you looking for `np.isclose(Y, 0., atol=radius)`, where Y is your collection of Y coordinates?

Comment: Yes a root is a point (x,y) such that f(x,y)=0. I don't have a collection of data and I'm not interested in small values per se, I'm interested in the question "is there a root in a given radius?". In 1d one can check for a sign change of the function inside some interval and that gives a definite answer to this question. But I'm interested in the 2d case..

Comment: Got it. How many roots does your function have? If there are lots, it may be beneficial to store your path points in a data structure that encapsulates a notion of distance such as a kD-tree (found in `scipy.spatial`). You could then query the kD-tree with your roots and look for neighbours around each root within a given radius. Also, if the points on your path are regularly spaced, then you can start by subsampling your path to points that are `2 * radius - epsilon` away from each other, and then expand outwards after the initial query.

Comment: @Paul analytically the function has infinitely many roots :/ So I wouldn't get around gridding space I guess.. And even with a kdtree, comparing >10000 roots with millions of other points to find those in proximity seems like too much computational effort.. But maybe I'll have to try something like this